# Pivot Method Implementation in PHP

Tags: mysql

I am trying pivot method to implement in PHP but its giving some error.

Table is `clientdetails` with 3 attributes (`clientname`,`productname`,`quantity`).

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("HR") or die(mysql_error());

    $sql=mysql_query("select clientname, 'Software' as s, 'Desktop' as d
    FROM (
        select clientname,productname,quantity
    FROM clientdetails)
    as p pivot (Sum(quantity) for productname in ('Software' ,'Desktop'))") or die("". mysql_error());
```

Its showing error as

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pivot (Sum(quantity) for productname in ('Software' ,'Desktop'))' at line 5 ".
```

Comment: Sidenote: you will probably want to read up on using something like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) in the future, when you have the chance... (some information about PDO and other options are listed on [this info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).)

Comment: MySQL server does not support PIVOT clause, but there are workarounds, have a look at these links: [MySQL pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/12-how-to-pivot-tables.html), [Dynamic pivot tables](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html).

Comment: pivot method is also not working in oracle.. 
Also the query in given link is also not working..!!

Please have a look 

select clientname, Sum(if(productname='Software',quantity,NULL))as Softwares
Sum(if(productname='Desktop',quantity,NULL))as Desktops
from clientdetails
group by clientname;